# How to save plotted image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Firstly, I am showing my image and put an hold on command to keep after operations.

```
figure,imshow(Ib_rgb)
hold on;
```

Then, I draw a line on that image.

```
plot([p1(2),p2(2)],[p1(1),p2(1)],'Color','r','LineWidth',2)
```

My question is, how to save this output image automatically ? 
Is there a way to name and save this image ?

There is a print function for it I guess, but I could not understand how to use in this situation easily ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at `saveas` command. It's really understandable. Just saves the figure to the desired format that you chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `saveas` and use `gcf` to get the current figure:

```
saveas(gcf,'image.png');
```

Comment: That is correct !  ' sign should be replaced with " , I think. Thanks.

Comment: @HilmiK MATLAB's [`string`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html) type, introduced in R2017a, [is created using `""`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-string-arrays.html). `char` arrays use `''`

Comment: @excaza Small correction: the string type as introduced in R2016b, although the " " notation doesn't work for me (on R2016b); perhaps this was introduced in R2017a?